# Must a DLL be multithread when called by a Delphi object?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, visual-c++

I derived a TMyThread object from TThread in Delphi, and in TMyThread.Execute, it will invoke a DLL written by Visual C++. In that case, must the DLL also compiled with the Multi-thread library and support multi-thread as well?

Comment: Not if you only plan to call it on this one thread. Yes if you plan to create several threads and call the DLL on them concurrently.

Comment: If COM is involved, don't forget CoInitialize.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of the MSVC runtime come in both multi-threaded and single-threaded variants. The difference is that the single-threaded variant does not protect against potential race conditions. So, if the code that calls into the MSVC runtime does so from more than one thread, the single-threaded runtime cannot be safely used.

The scenario that you describe has only a single thread executing code inside your MSVC DLL. In which case the single-threaded MSVC runtime is safe to use. It does not matter that the host executable is multi-threaded. All that counts is whether multiple threads call into the MSVC runtime attached to your MSVC DLL.

MSVC stopped shipping separate single-threaded and multi-threaded runtimes many releases ago. One wonders whether or not it makes a difference to your application. Can you detect any performance difference between the two runtime options. If not then it would make sense to me to use the multi-threaded runtime. Choosing the single-threaded runtime is just storing up a potential debugging headache when you forget about this in a future change to the code and introduce extra threads to your MSVC DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ DLL should be MT, if you intend to use it MT. If you intend to use it from only one single thread of your application, then you don't have to do that. But you should clearly document this as soon as you have the slightest doubt that there could be a thread conflict, e.g. with data structures internally managed within the DLL. Or use MT anyway, take care of proper locking and forget about it. (My previous Delphi statement still stands true).

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question asked. The question is about whether the MSVC DLL needs to be multi-thread aware. Anything posted as an answer should actually answer the question. What you've posted is a comment instead, and should be posted as one to the original question. SO isn't a discussion forum or newsgroup. :-)

Comment: Ehm - correct. I read/answered too quick obviously. Thanks for the hint, Ken. => Done.